# How to automate testing R Shiny app for Continuous delivery?

Tags: r, shiny

I have built an R Shiny application which has a git repository, how to implement continuous delivery such that every time I push any changes to code, I can run another github repository containing the test cases on the main repository and it tests are successfull then the changes will be represented to production git repository.

Comment: Please elaborate your question, it needs more context.

Comment: Have a look at `shinytest` https://rstudio.github.io/shinytest/articles/ci.html and here https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-testing-gha-example

Comment: Where is the production git repository hosted? The question of how to do any kind of CI on a git repo is predicated on one of two things, either: (a) the git repo itself must notify *something* when a push-event occurs; or (b) a remote site must poll the git repo periodically to determine if a push-event occurred. Obviously the latter is much less efficient, but if your production git repo does not have the built-in ability to do that, you're in for a world of hacks and/or git-scripts.